# Git workflow and gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I've current using the following setup and I'm wondering if I should have followed a different path..

Online server <> Offline Dev <> Offline Gitlab

Online Server gets a few updates (mainly uploads) so I pull those to my Offline Dev.

Offline Dev is where I work. I push the changes to the online Server and to the Offline Gitlab so I can track the changes.

Offline Gitlab just tracks the changes and nothing more. I would like to only push specific folders here but I am not sure how I am supposed to do it.

Is my method OK and is it possible to achieve the last step regarding the gitlab (I don't want to push all the changes there so if it is possible to ignore a few folders)

Comment: Maybe using `.gitignore` files would let you selectively push the folders you want.  But in general, doing a push in Git is like taking a photograph of your entire workspace; all files go all at once (minus what you have chosen to ignore).